# What type of virus protections are available and their suitability to a cyber-security company.

Tags: operating-systems

What type of virus protections are available and their suitability to a cyber-security company.  I'm talking about top notch stuff. Are there any methods or techniques that are rare or unusual? Othere than Anti-Virus softwares, are there other ways to keep your systems protected from virus?

Comment: Questions about specific products or software packages are off-topic here; this site is about the science and concepts.  Also, the question is too broad, as it is asking for an overview of an entire area.  One could write an entire book about defending a corporation against viruses and similar attacks.  You might want to spend some time with search on [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com) to read through what people have already written about over there.  Do note there help page for advice about how to ask a good question about security.